# Wired connection keeps disconnecting on 16.04 with ASRock Z370M Pro 4

Tags: 16.04, networking

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04, on asrock Z370M Pro 4 (Giga PHY Intel® I219V).

My wired connection keeps breaking constantly, in random intervals.
It works for 20/30 sec, up to a minute, than it disconnects for 20-30 sec up to 2 minutes.

Here are some terminal outputs:

```
dmesg | grep e100
[    0.924486] e1000e: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Driver - 3.2.6-k
[    0.924486] e1000e: Copyright(c) 1999 - 2015 Intel Corporation.
[    0.993761] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6: Interrupt Throttling Rate (ints/sec) set to dynamic conservative mode
[    1.196239] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 0000:00:1f.6 (uninitialized): registered PHC clock
[    1.263770] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 eth0: (PCI Express:2.5GT/s:Width x1) 70:85:c2:82:8d:3e
[    1.263771] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 eth0: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Connection
[    1.263879] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 eth0: MAC: 12, PHY: 12, PBA No: FFFFFF-0FF
[    1.264564] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 eno1: renamed from eth0
[    6.082388] e1000e: eno1 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: Rx/Tx
```

```
sudo lshw -C network
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Connection (2) I219-V
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.6
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
       logical name: eno1
       version: 00
       serial: 70:85:c2:82:8d:3e
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k duplex=full firmware=0.2-4 ip=192.168.0.71 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:125 memory:df200000-df21ffff
```

```
ip -c a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 70:85:c2:82:8d:3e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.71/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global dynamic eno1
       valid_lft 8635954sec preferred_lft 8635954sec
    inet6 fe80::231:1684:a81b:642e/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

```
lspci -nnk | grep 0200 -A2
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (2) I219-V [8086:15b8]
    DeviceName: Onboard - Ethernet
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Ethernet Connection (2) I219-V [1849:15b8]
```

```
systemctl status NetworkManager.service --no-pager -l
● NetworkManager.service - Network Manager
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Čet 2019-05-23 07:39:33 CEST; 1h 10min ago
     Docs: man:NetworkManager(8)
 Main PID: 852 (NetworkManager)
   CGroup: /system.slice/NetworkManager.service
           ├─ 852 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon
           ├─1252 /sbin/dhclient -d -q -sf /usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-helper -pf /var/run/dhclient-eno1.pid -lf /var/lib/NetworkManager/dhclient-5357f85c-b235-3538-afb1-dc96f8d64329-eno1.lease -cf /var/lib/NetworkManager/dhclient-eno1.conf eno1
           └─1262 /usr/sbin/dnsmasq --no-resolv --keep-in-foreground --no-hosts --bind-interfaces --pid-file=/var/run/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.pid --listen-address=127.0.1.1 --cache-size=0 --conf-file=/dev/null --proxy-dnssec --enable-dbus=org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.dnsmasq --conf-dir=/etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d

Svi 23 07:39:36 user-desktop dnsmasq[1262]: DBus support enabled: connected to system bus
Svi 23 07:39:36 user-desktop dnsmasq[1262]: warning: no upstream servers configured
Svi 23 07:39:36 user-desktop NetworkManager[852]: <info>  [1558589976.8843] device (eno1): Activation: successful, device activated.
Svi 23 07:39:36 user-desktop NetworkManager[852]: <info>  [1558589976.8854] dnsmasq[0x202ace0]: dnsmasq appeared as :1.42
Svi 23 07:39:36 user-desktop dnsmasq[1262]: setting upstream servers from DBus
Svi 23 07:39:36 user-desktop dnsmasq[1262]: using nameserver 192.168.0.150#53(via eno1)
Svi 23 07:39:36 user-desktop dnsmasq[1262]: using nameserver 193.198.184.130#53(via eno1)
Svi 23 07:39:41 user-desktop NetworkManager[852]: <info>  [1558589981.7043] manager: startup complete
Svi 23 07:39:43 user-desktop NetworkManager[852]: <info>  [1558589983.7035] manager: WiFi hardware radio set enabled
Svi 23 07:39:43 user-desktop NetworkManager[852]: <info>  [1558589983.7035] manager: WWAN hardware radio set enabled
```

```
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
701 packets transmitted, 359 received, 48% packet loss, time 708752ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 49.605/49.798/57.470/0.700 ms
```

Other PCs (on Windows) work fine connected to the same switch.

Any help is much appreciated!

I'm an absolute beginner with Linux, so please take that in mind when trying to help.

Thanks!

Comment: Ubuntu desktop configures with `network-manager` module. Can you print the contents of `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` in a pastebin file?

Comment: [main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

Comment: try to change `managed=false` to `managed=true` and do `sudo service network-manager restart`

Comment: I've done what you suggested, unfortunately it seems there's no change.